# Why does Collection Editor return null?

Tags: c#

[image: ScreenShot]

I'm trying to create a custom control which has a collection of items, but nothing appears on design-time even if I rebuild the project.

(Parents) is custom control

How can I make it appear in the collection editor without losing it after rebuilding the project.

```
public class ItemsTest : UserControl
    {
        Parents parent;
        ObjectCollections itm ;

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public ObjectCollections Items { get { return itm; } }
        public ItemsTest ()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            itm = new ObjectCollections(this);
            parent = new Parents();
        }
    }

    public class ObjectCollections : CollectionBase
    {

        private List<Parents> _contents;

        private ItemsTest itemstest = null;
        public ObjectCollections(ItemsTest owner)
        {
            _contents = new List<Parents>();
            this.itemstest = owner;
        }

        public int IndexOf(Parents item)
        {
            return _contents.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert(int index, Parents item)
        {
            _contents.Insert(index, item);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            _contents.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public Parents this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return _contents[index];
            }
            set
            {
                _contents[index] = value;
            }
        }

        public void Add(Parents item)
        {
            _contents.Add(item);
            this.itemstest.Controls.Add(item);
            this.itemstest.Invalidate();
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _contents.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(Parents item)
        {
            if (_contents.Contains(item))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public void CopyTo(Parents[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            for (int _oj = 0; _oj < Count; _oj++)
            {
                array.SetValue(_contents[_oj], arrayIndex++);
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _contents.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Remove(Parents item)
        {
            return _contents.Remove(item);
        }


        IEnumerator<Parents> IEnumerable<Parents>.GetEnumerator()
        {
           //some code
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
```

When I try to add items into the collection editor, rebuild the project, and reopen the collection editor nothing is shown in it.

Comment: `throw new NotImplementedException();` ???

Comment: Can this help you https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListBox.cs,062167a740ca5308 & https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,256d820b599d66f1 ?